# How to make YouTube style notification?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, youtube, android-notifications

I need to customize notification of YouTube style.
but, I couldn't find any app with the style.

Does it use only YouTube?

Please your advise.

```
Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(" ")
                .setContentText(description)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setColor(context.getColor(R.color.notification_default_color))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setStyle(Notification.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
                .setGroup(notificationType.summaryGroupKey)
                .setActions(*actions)
                .setCustomContentView(smallView)
                .setCustomBigContentView(expandedView)
```

Comment: can you post a picture what you want to achieve

Comment: you can see new youtube notification - https://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/nexus2cee_youtube-notification-hero.png

Answer (score 0):

I found a way.

It's a combination of customized RemoteView and BigPictureStyle.

```
val builder = Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(description)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setColor(context.getColor(R.color.notification_default_color))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setStyle(Notification.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmap))
                .setActions(*actions)
                .setCustomContentView(smallView)
```

The customized RemoteView has own UI component instead of the app icon, the app name, and etc.

I could make it similar to the original UI.

It was some trick.